# ng test fails because of SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import

Tags: angular, sass

I have several `.scss` files that I import in my components which are contained within modules. When I build my project for dev or for prod everything is fine, but when I run `ng test` I see a bunch of errors saying something like:

```
SassError: SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.

1 │ @import "mixins";
```

This happens for every imported `.scss` file in my modules. Shared styles are placed in `src/assets/styles` directory like this:

```
-src
  -assets
    -styles
      -_mixins.scss
      -_theme.scss
      ...etc
```

In my `angular.json` I have the following properties:

```
"styles": ["src/styles.scss"],
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
  "includePaths": ["src/assets/styles"]
},
```

I've tried referencing all my styles in main `style.scss`, but to no avail. The main thing that buggers me is that in dev and prod mode everything works fine, it's just the tests that bring these errors and I can't figure a way to fix this.

```
Angular version is 10.0.5
Sass version is 1.26.5
Sass loader version is 8.0.2
```

Comment: Can you post all your angular.json please? or at least `ng-test` and `ng-build/serve` sections?

Comment: Please double check whether you are running `ng test` from your root directory.

Comment: @RazRonen Thank you very much! I haven't figured out that `ng-test` section should include its own `includePaths` property.

Comment: @uiTeam324 thank you...made me feel dumb but fixed my problem.

Answer (score 18):

This question has been answered several times already. Please also use the search and vote for questions and answers.

On Stackoverflow:
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50210311/sass-loader-requires-node-sass-4-even-if-that-exist)
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57971347/ng-test-fails-in-angular-universal-error-incomplete-no-specs-found-randomiz)
[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44460733/how-to-configure-karma-to-include-global-scss-files-for-an-angular-cli-project)

On the AngularCLI on Github:
[1](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11212)

**To fix this import and add to preprocessor.**

Update your `angular.json` file in the patch `projects.NAME.architect.test` with this

```
"styles": ["src/styles.scss"],
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
  "includePaths": ["src/assets/styles"]
},
```

Comment: I think It is mentioned that this line is already added in the angular.json

Comment: well, yes, see comments above. `ng-test section should include its own includePaths`. The error was that includePaths did not include styles, as my answer states. dont know why down voted, but that's how Stackoverflow works no?

Answer (score 0):

It does appear that in angular.json there are multiple sections that need the "styles" and "styleprocessor", once in projects/architect/build/options (see below) AND  projects/architect/**test**/options too!

```
"projects":{
           ...
    "architect":{ 
                 ...
                 "build": {
                          ...
                          "options": {
                                ....
                                    "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
                                        "includePaths": ["node_modules"]
                                     },
                                    "styles": [
                                     {
                                       "input": "node_modules/@module_name/whatever_style.scss",
                                      }

                           }
                }
}
```